# mercurial repository is not appearing in the list of repositorries

Tags: mercurial, repository

Mercurial repository is pushed on the server but it is not appearing in the list. I can see it created under the folder of repositories. Any idea what is missing.

Previous Repository Struture : test1
                               test2

I have added another repository with the name test3. but This one is not appearing when browsing via url. http://hg.test.com
           test1
           test2

Comment: As is, it is very difficult to understand your question, where does the repository is supposed to appear ? Are you using some kind of repository listing server side ?

Comment: Yes creating on server side

Comment: And by "server side", what kind of server is this?